# Why I can't take innerText value of p in the test?

Tags: javascript, html, jestjs

I have a simple function which gets data of the element with id and returns it. In my browser it runs well, but in the test function throws error that elem.innerText is undefined. How to fix that error?
To fix it, I tried changing tags, and added elem variable as a marker(I can see that that tag is avialable from the function, debug shows that variable is visible, but value is undefined. So substring throws that error.

> Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

). So now I don't know how to fix that error and asking for help. Here are my test and function.

```
export function getSum(){
    let elem = document.getElementById('allsum');
    let value = document.getElementById('allsum').innerText;
    return 1*value.substring(0,value.indexOf('U'));
}

test('Testing getting the sum',()=>{
    document.body.innerHTML = '<p id="allsum">100UAH</p>';
    expect(getSum()).toEqual(100);
})
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I added description of the error.

Comment: Why do you define the variable `elem`, then not use it on the next line?

Comment: Does it work if you use `textContent` instead of `innerText`?

Comment: `innerText` is non-standard. Depending on the test environment, it may simply not exist.

Comment: Well, it's [in the standard now](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute), but yeah, you really shouldn't be using it, might not be supported

Comment: @Barmar, it works. Thansk everyone very much